# Google Search Console: existing sitemap not found

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, 404, crawl-errors

Google search console (at Crawl -> Sitemaps) gives me General HTTP error: 404 not found errors after I upload the sitemap.xml to my website. When I click the link generated in the search console, it opens the file, but Search console still gives me 404 error.

[image]

Comment: It could just be just another Google oddity that we have all become rather used to here. I suggest waiting a few days or weeks and see what happens. Check your access log files. I am sure Google will find your sitemap okay in time. Keep in mind that sitemaps are hardly useful or necessary. They are mostly only used by Google only to audit whether the regular googlebot can crawl your site okay. Otherwise, they are only useful for sites that are extremely large or for content that is behind a login or paywall. Cheers!!

Comment: Here is a related question with the solution: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104110/google-search-console-404-errors-on-existing-pages

Comment: Huh! Hacker and .htaccess. Who wudda thunk it? Thanks for the update. Did this happen in your case?? Cheers!!