# Google Search Console: 404 errors on existing pages

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot, 404, crawl-errors

There is a few years old small website with very few pages (~5), which were indexed and ranked by Google. A few days ago 4 of those pages disappeared from SERPs and Search Console gives me 404 Not Found errors despite the fact that the pages are up and running. I didn't do any changes in header's crawler related meta tags and robot.txt neither.

Tried to submit a sitemap.xml but [it gives me 404 error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103958/google-search-console-existing-sitemap-not-found) for that too.

What causes this problem?

Comment: "Search Console gives me 404 Not Found errors" - is that using the _Fetch as Google_ tool? If that still reports a 404 then check your `.htaccess` file (eg. in case of hack that diverts Googlebot).

Comment: @DocRoot You were right. This was the problem. You should give this comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Google is reporting these pages as a 404 (and this has been confirmed with the "Fetch as Google" tool in Google Search Console), yet they appear to be perfectly accessible and return a 200 OK when visiting the site then check your `.htaccess` file for any suspicious code that might be redirecting the Googlebot.

If a hacker is able to inject code into `.htaccess` then they can very quickly destroy a sites ranking. Unfortunately, if they've been able to edit `.htaccess` then this might not be the only thing they have done.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ssl certificate can cause the problem too. If your page is on https and you hadn't redirected it with .htaccess, it gives you 404 error.

Comment: Have you seen Google Search Console report of 404 error for an SSL error?   Google is usually good at reporting the specific error.  I would expect that to result in a crawl error of some kind, but I wouldn't expect a 404.